# Calculate percentile rank (Parse)

Tags: javascript, math, parse-platform, nosql

I need to calculate the percentile rank of a particular value against a large number of values filtered in various different ways. The data is all stored on Parse.com, which has a limitation of returning a maximum of 1000 rows per query. The number of values stored is likely to exceed well over 100,000.

By 'percentile rank', I mean I need to calculate the percentage of values that the provided value is greater than. I am **not** trying to calculate the value of a provided percentile. For example, given a list of values {20, 23, 24, 29, 30, 31, 35, 40, 40, 43} the percentile rank of the provided value 35 is 70%. The algorithm for this is simply the rank of the value / count of values * 100. Not sure if 'percentile rank' is the correct terminology for this.

I have considered a couple of different approaches to this. The first is to pull down the full list of values (into Parse Cloud) and then calculate the percentile rank from there, then filter the list and calculate again, repeating the last two steps as many times as required. The problem with this approach is it will not work once we reach 1000 values, which we can expect pretty quickly.

Another option, which is the best I can come up with so far, is to query the count of items, and the rank of the provided value. For example:

```
var rank_world_alltime = new Parse.Query("Values")
    .lessThan("value", request.params.value)  // Filters query to values less than the provided value, so counting this query will return the rank
    .count();

var count_world_alltime = new Parse.Query("Values")
    .count();

Parse.Promise.when(rank_world_alltime, count_world_alltime).then(function(rank, count) {
    percentile = rank / count * 100;
    console.log("world_alltime_percentile = " + percentile);
});
```

This works well for a single calculation, but I need to perform multiple calculations, and this approach very quickly becomes a lot of queries. I expect to need to run about 15 calculations per call, which is 30 queries. All calculations need to complete in under 3 seconds before Parse terminates the job, and I am limited to 30 reqs/second, so this is very quickly going to become a problem.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how else I could approach this? I've thought about somehow pre-processing some of this but can't quite work out how to do so, as the filters will be based on time and location (city and country), so there are potentially a LOT of pre-calculations that will need to be run at regular intervals. The results do not need to be 100% accurate but something close.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about parse, but as far as I understand what you say, it is some kind of cloud database thingy that holds your hiscores, and limits you 1000 rows per query, 3 seconds per job, and 30 queries per second.

In order to have approximate calculations and divide by 2 the number of queries, I would first of all cache the total (count_world_alltime, count_region,week, whatever). If you can save them somewhere locally. For numbers of 100K just getting the order of magnitude (thus not the latest updated number) should be good enough to get a percentile.

Maybe you can get several counts per query. However my lack of expertise in parse/nosql kind of stops me from being sure of this, you'll have to check their documentation. If it is possible however, for the case where you need percentiles for a serie of values all in the same category, I would

- Order the values, let's call them a,b,c,d,e (once ordered)
- Get the number of values between the intervals [0,a] [a,b] [b,c] [c,d] [d,e]
- Use the cached total to get the percentiles (where Nxy is the number of values in [x,y]) :

  - Pa = 100 * N0a / total
  - Pb = 100 * ( N0a + Nab ) / total
  - Pc = 100 * ( N0a + Nab + Nbc ) / total
  - and so on...

If you need a value ranked worldwide, the other per region, some per week others over all times, etc, this doesn't apply. In that case I don't think you can get below 1 query/number, with caching the totals.

Comment: Thanks for your input @Cimblali. This is an interesting approach which would be useful in a slightly different scenario. It doesn't quite fit my requirements (I need values ranked worldwide, per country/city, per specific time interval, as well as a combination of each of these - city for last week, country for last week, etc) but might be able to use a similar approach. I'm thinking my best bet may be to move to an SQL based backend..

Comment: @JoGoFo Well, too bad. Hopefully you can still cache the total numbers. Though these requests might run pretty fast, supposing you have indexes or something like that, it will still help you with the limit on the total number of requests.